# grouping rows while being able to show columns from each row in the group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sure the title is not clear enough, couldn't find a better way to explain what I need.

I'm using PostGreSQL 11.4

i'll minify the problem i'm having to show the actual issue.

I have a query that returns the following:

```
id  |  time | direction | name
------------------------------
1       0        1        foo1
1       0        2        foo2
1       1        1        foo3
1       1        2        foo4
2       2        1        foo5
2       2        2        foo6
3       3        2        foo7
```

what I would like to do is to group by `id, time` and to add two new columns: `name_direction1` and `name_direction2`

so the result table would be:

```
id | time | name_direction1 | name_direction2

1     0        foo1               foo2
1     1        foo3               foo4
2     2        foo5               foo6
3     3                           foo7
```

as far as I know with `group by` I can't really reach each one of the rows. in my case I need to combine two rows when both directions are presented.

any ideas how to achieve this?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  id, time,
  max(case direction when 1 then name end) name_direction_1,
  max(case direction when 2 then name end) name_direction_2
from tablename
group by id, time
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/49kZA4CLZ2LTjNqqxvEwHE/0).
Results:

```
| id  | time | name_direction_1 | name_direction_2 |
| --- | ---- | ---------------- | ---------------- |
| 1   | 0    | foo1             | foo2             |
| 1   | 1    | foo3             | foo4             |
| 2   | 2    | foo5             | foo6             |
| 3   | 3    |                  | foo7             |
```

Comment: than you for your response, unfortunately once I add the max (case) lines, it asks me to add to the "group by" all the fields that i selected in the query. any ideas ?

Comment: All the columns in the select list must either appear in the group by clause or be aggregated and this done in this code.

Comment: I apologize for accepting it too quickly i was trying to play with the query and I'm asking for like 50 different fields from the table and now it seems that somehow I need to aggregate all of those fields. again i'm new to postgresql but the rest of the columns are identical between the lines and it sounded weird for me that I need to aggregate all of the fields, i'll play with it a bit more just to figure out what's going on

Comment: In your question you have 4 columns, not 50. If you need aggregation for all of them, you will need a separate sum(case...) for each one of them.